# How do I pass an empty list in Scala while avoiding the Head of Empty List Error?

Tags: list, scala, queue, stack

I'm trying to implement a Banker's Queue in Scala, and keep encountering the head of empty list runtime error around line 13. A Banker's Queue enqueues into one stack (push to s1), and dequeues from the other stack (pop from s1 and push to s2 (in reverse order just because)).

Since I'm using `vals` that are immutable, I cannot 'pop' from either `s1` or `s2`.

So when `s2` is `Nil` (empty list) and a `dequeue` operation is called, I need to add every value in `s1` to `s2`, and return two values: s2.head, and a `new TwoStackQueue` object consisting of the empty list `s1` (because I 'emptied' the entire list), and `s2.tail`.

As previously mentioned, if `s2` is empty, I need to transfer all values from `s1`. This means `s1` is 'empty', and so I reasoned that in this case, I'd need to pass an empty list to the `TwoStackQueue` constructor. However, I cannot get past the `head of empty list` error that's thrown at me.

I'd greatly appreciate any insight to my problem. Thank you!

```
class TwoStackQueue[A](s1 : List[A], s2 : List[A]) {

  def this() = this(Nil, Nil) // auxiliary constructor

  def enqueue(x : A) : TwoStackQueue[A] =  {

    new TwoStackQueue(s1:+x, s2);
  }
  
  def dequeue() : (A, TwoStackQueue[A]) = { 
    if(s2.isEmpty) {
      s2 ::: s1.reverse;
      (s2.head, new TwoStackQueue(List.empty[A], s2.tail));
    } else {
      (s2.head, new TwoStackQueue(s1, s2.tail));
    }
  }
}

object TwoStackQueue {

  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
      val q1  = new TwoStackQueue[Int]();

      val q2 = q1.enqueue(1);
      val q3 = q2.enqueue(2);
      
      val (x,q4) = q3.dequeue()
      println(x);  // Should print 1

      val q5 = q4.enqueue(3);

      val (y,q6) = q5.dequeue()
      println(y); // Should print 2 
      val (z,q7) = q6.dequeue()
      println(z); // Should print 3
  }  
}
```

Comment: `s2 ::: s1.reverse;` this is doing nothing, as you said, `List` is immutable, that operation is creating a new `List` but you don't store that anywhere.

Comment: This is how to properly implement a `Queue` using two `Stacks`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/RE7Wi7t1TbWb179AYjmB5Q/2

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you, I'll take a look after I've given the problem some more thought as I'm trying to learn!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez also, how am I not storing the new list created by s1.reverse? Am I not appending it to s2 with the ::: operator? Thanks!

Comment: `:::` just like `reverse` and any other operator on an immutable `List` just returns a new `List` which you are not storing anywhere.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Is this what's causing the `head of empty list` error that's being thrown?

Comment: Yes, because you then try to access `s2.head` but `s2` is empty.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Great, thanks so much. Just to make sure I'm getting everything, s1.reverse isn't being properly stored, so when s2 is empty and I try appending s1.reverse to s2 with the ::: operator, it is appending nothing. Thus, I have to create a new list (newList) and set it equal to s1.reverse to store it, which enables me to do s2 ::: newList.

Comment: Actually `s1.reverse` while not explicitly stored in a variable, is not lost is passed to the `:::` method. Is the result of the whole expression the one that is being discarded, you may do something like `val s3 = s2 ::: s1.reverse` - But, since `s2` is empty that is unnecessary, you can just `val s3 = s1.reverse` - BTW, you have some other bugs.